# How to get response code from a button in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a iframe embedded in a page, the iframe points to third party api . Is there any way i can get the response on button in a iframe.

pseudo code will be like

On button press inside a iframe get the response code.

Answer (score 1):

Window.postMessage()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

This would do!

Comment: The iframe is using get method  and i dont have control over there javascript. I want to check if the respone code is 200 when the button is clicked

Comment: First you cannot take control over Third Party URL;  That provider has to implement this postMessage() in iframe URL and you have to put receiveMessage();  in your page.  This can do what you are expecting